# Monitoring CYPHER queries performance in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, profiling, cypher, database-performance, neo4jclient

I am using Neo4JClient to connect to my Neo4J database and execute CYPHER queries. My goal is to check performance of queries I send to database. Problem is that I have to check it on the db side so I can't use Stopwatch in .NET. Queries have to be executed using Neo4JClient. I don't need to know execution times for specific queries. I.e. average for last 1000 queries will be enough.

I can use only Neo4J Community Edition.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j Enterprise Edition has the capability to log slow queries taking longer than a given threshold, see the config settings containing `querylog` on http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-settings.html.

Comment: As I said I can only use Community Edition because it's an academic project.